# How to access Contacts in Windows 8 People app from another app

Tags: windows-8, contacts, windows-store-apps

Does anyone know how to access Contacts in Windows 8 Store apps?
I know that because of the sandboxed nature, Windows Store apps cannot access AddressBook from files such as Outlook Express contacts or Outlook, but since there is already an app called People that comes pre-installed, I figure why not let users make use of whatever Contacts the user has already allowed the app to see, rather than creating separate list of Contacts for my app. It seems silly to recreate the wheel by asking the user to re-import all the contacts again.
I have seen Contact Picker example but I still have no clues how to get list of Contacts/People as in that People app.

I have not developed for mobile phone, however if the device is a mobile phone, surely the app is expected to use local contacts rather than keeping separate list of contacts. So I am thinking there's got to be a way to do the same thing on a PC or any device really, rather than each app managing its own contacts. I have not seen any guidance on how to do this. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question a few days ago and, after a lot of research, it looks like it's just not possible to get that information from the people app outside of the contract. The reason that it works within calendar/mail/messenger is because they're all technically contained within the same app and are able to use each other's data and violate normal rules.

A lot of people have pointed me to look at the live SDK, but it still seems like it's not at all possible to get people information in your app, since the SDK doesn't support it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ContactPicker class :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br224913.aspx

Another way is to share your resource or whatever you want to send and user will choose an app that will send or on any another way use your shared resource (url, image, whatever)
IMO the latter is preferred way since then user will have a choice of applications that can send mail or post that resource on facebook / twitter.

Comment: ContactPicker only works if you already have Contacts to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1) sample on [ContactPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR224913)

Comment: It is not about picking some contacts you already have on the app, but how to get list of contacts you can work with together with other apps that use same list of contacts.
As I have mentioned, I have looked at ContactPicker example and it does not address my question. Thanks anyway for commenting.